# Pulling numbers from an ArrayList

Tags: java, url, arraylist

I am trying to figure out the total and average salaries of some professors from a text file at a URL.  I can read the data and assign it to an ArrayList based on if that line contains the rank of the professor, but what I can't figure out is how to take the salaries of each rank pull that number out to add up and then average. I know that once I get the number out I should probably parse it to a double, but I don't know how to pull the numbers out.  My original goal was to have each line in the file be a separate object, but I couldn't figure out how so I just did it this way. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class University {

private ArrayList<String> all = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> associate = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> assistant = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> full = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    University u = new University();

    }

private void read() throws MalformedURLException{
    URL data = new URL ("http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/Salary.txt");
    try{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(data.openStream());
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            line.split(" ");
            all.add(line);
            if(line.contains("associate"))
                associate.add(line);
            else if(line.contains("assistant"))
                assistant.add(line);
            else if(line.contains("full"))
                full.add(line);
        }
        scan.close();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
}

private double totalSalary(ArrayList<String> rank){
    //Rank = name of the ArrayList you want
}
```

}

Also, at the end in the totalSalary method, am I doing that properly?  I've worked with ArrayLists before, but I've never done anything like that with them before since I'm relatively new to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
    public class Test {

        public class Teacher {

            String firstName;
            String lastName;
            String rank;
            Double salary;

            public Teacher(String firstName, String lastName, String rank,
                    Double salary) {
                super();
                this.firstName = firstName;
                this.lastName = lastName;
                this.rank = rank;
                this.salary = salary;
            }

        }

        ArrayList<Teacher> result = new ArrayList<Teacher>();

        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
            Test u = new Test();
            u.read();
            u.printAverages();
        }

        private void printAverages() {
            Iterator<Teacher> iterator = result.iterator();
            double assistantHolder = 0, assistantCounter = 0, 
                   assosiatedHolder = 0, assosiatedCounter = 0,
                   fullHolder = 0, fullCounter = 0;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Teacher teacher = iterator.next();
                if (teacher.rank.equals("associate")) {
                    assosiatedHolder += teacher.salary;
                    assosiatedCounter++;
                } else if (teacher.rank.equals("assistant")) {
                    assistantHolder += teacher.salary;
                    assistantCounter++;
                } else if (teacher.rank.equals("full")) {
                    fullHolder += teacher.salary;
                    fullCounter++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Associate average:"+(assosiatedHolder/assosiatedCounter));
            System.out.println("Assistant average:"+(assistantHolder/assistantCounter));
            System.out.println("Full average:"+(fullHolder/fullCounter));
        }

        private ArrayList<Teacher> read() throws MalformedURLException {
            URL data = new URL("http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/Salary.txt");
            try {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(data.openStream());
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    String line = scan.nextLine();
                    String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+",4);
                    String firstName = tokens[0], lastName = tokens[1], rank = tokens[2];
                    Double salary = Double.valueOf(tokens[3]);
                    result.add(new Teacher(firstName, lastName, rank, salary));
                }
                scan.close();
                return result;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that  must be some cleaner way to do it. Byes!

Answer (score 0):

To get a value out, call [ArrayList.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29).  Do that for every element (in a loop) and keep track of the sum in a variable outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use three x 2 = six class variables that define the sum and average of salaries of the three ranks you have (full, associate and assistant). Your if logic is still fine, whenever an if condition matches, add that corresponding salary to the total of the specific class variable. Once you are done, you can calculate the average by sum/array_list.size();

Comment: I see what you are saying, but since the ArrayList is a string I would have to parse the salary to a double wouldn't I? I can't figure out how to separate the numbers from regular words to do that.  I remember seeing something about it at one point and time, but I don't remember where I saw it or how to do it.